# Increment numbers inside a text in microsoft excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like to drag cells downward and increases the number next to letters. It work when there is no letter for me.

For example, I want to increment the number this way

```
AG1
AG2
AG3
AG4
...
```

I don't know what if formula should I use. If there is no letters and only numbers, I use something like `=A1+1` and then a I drag the cells to increase the number by 1, but this does not work when there is letters

Comment: the simplest way is to use ROW() on the value of your string

Answer (score 4):

For me, this works straight out of the box.

In A1 type AG1

In A2 type AG2

Then select both cells and drag them down together (You already know this but I put it in for completeness: Hover the mouse over the bottom right of the selection. The cursor will turn into a small but thick black cross. Hold the left mouse button and drag down).

[If this fails you can implement a custom list](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-list-for-sorting-and-filling-data-d1cf624f-2d2b-44fa-814b-ba213ec2fd61)

> ```
> Click the Microsoft Office Button Office button image, and then click Excel Options.
>
> Click the Popular category, and then under Top options for working with Excel, click Edit Custom Lists.
>
> In the Custom Lists box, click NEW LIST, and then type the entries in the List entries box, beginning with the first entry.
>
> Press ENTER after each entry.
>
> When the list is complete, click Add.
>
> The items in the list that you selected are added to the Custom lists box.
>
> Click OK twice.
> ```

Answer (score 4):

@Dave's solution is correct for manually populating the data.

If you need a formula for arbitrary ranges/tables, use:

```
="AG" & ROW() - 1
```

where `1` is the row number of your table header (above formula will put value `AG1` into 2nd row).

If you already have numbers as the value of some other formula and you want to change the display of the numbers to include "AG" prefix:

1. right click your selection > `Format Cells...`
2. on `Number` tab, choose `Custom`
3. type `"AG"General` as your custom number format

(Use `"AG"0` if you need to convert possibly floating point numbers to nearest lower integer value)